# What .Net version to select from when creating App Service in Azure for project based on .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have created a web app using ASP.NET 5 Core. It was released in 2019.  When I went to deploy on Azure App Service in general settings when selecting a .NET version I do not see an option for .NET 5. Although there is option for 3.1. When I tried to read the notes, I found that Microsoft stopped supporting the 5.

So my questions are:

1. What should I select so .NET 5 can be installed in an App Service? I think .NET 6 should be backward compatible and should work, but I did not read a precise note which say that. I am looking for doc which confirms that.
2. Why is .NET 5 not being supported by MS anymore, but 3.1 is?

Comment: *Why is .NET 5 not being supported by MS anymore, but 3.1 is* - ask MS Marketing..... .NET Core 3.1 is defined as a **LTS** (long-term support = 3 years from release in Nov 2019) version, while .NET 5 is "only" a "current" release, which is supported 6 months after its successor (.NET 6 - was released in Nov 2021) is released. Why - ask marketing ....

Comment: Okay so you also have questions which makes me feel better.  Anyway lets move to the first question.  What to select if I am creating a App service for my app in general settings for .Net Framework when my app is written in .Net 5?

Comment: The easiest would be to just write your code in .NET 6 and host it based on .NET 6 - can you do that? Upgrading from .NET 5 to .NET 6 should be a breeze ...

Answer (score 0):

> What .Net version to select from when creating App Service in Azure for project based on .NET 5?

- As per this [MS .Net blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/#update-your-application), it clearly says and strongly recommend you upgrade to `.NET 6.0`, long-term support version.
- Use .NET 6.0 with Visual Studio 2022

> Why is .NET 5 not being supported by MS anymore, but 3.1 is?

.NET 5 was a temporary version that was a short term, whereas .NET 3.1 is a long-term support version.

Thanks to @marc_s, I do agree with his comments.

You can refer this [.NET Core release lifecycle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle)

.NET 5 was supported till `10 May 2022`, whereas .NET 3 is available till 13 Dec 2022 and .NET 6 up to 12 Nov 2024